# how to compress an extremely large (1 million pixel x 1 million pixel) P4 PBM file into PNG

Tags: images, png

I have a 128GB .pbm file for the Mandelbrot set, and I would like to compress this into a PNG file so it takes up far less space. is there any feasible way to convert a file this large, I only have 32GB of ram which is not enough to open it in a image editing program to convert it.

Comment: OS? OS family? Anything goes?

Comment: Have you tried Photoshop's Image Processor? Ps is pretty good at *not* loading an entire file in order to process. If it needs to, its scratch disk ought to be good for it, assuming you have disk space.

Comment: You shouldn't need 128 GB of memory to open a photo at that resolution.  Most photo editors don't even load the entire image into memory only a small section of the image (entirely based on different factors).  I believe the real problem you have is the resolution of the image itself, not the size of the file.  [Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/optimize-photoshop-cc-performance.html) only supports a maximum of 30,000 x 30,000 pixels which is several factors smaller than your image. In order to do that of course it uses your system memory and a cache (scratch) drive.

Comment: I imagine `libvips` would do that in a very memory-efficient way `vips copy INPUT.PBM OUTPUT.PNG`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tool that might be able to do this conversion is
[ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)
which can be downloaded for Windows
[from here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).

The wiki page
[Large Image Support](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#tera-pixel)
says this about its limits:

> ImageMagick can read, process, or write mega-, giga-, or tera-pixel image sizes. An image width or height can range from 1 to 2 giga-pixels on a 32 bit OS (up to 2147483647 rows/columns) and up to 9 exa-pixels on a 64-bit OS (up to 9223372036854775807 rows/columns).

The above article suggests some methods for limiting memory usage, if required,
for example by forcing the image pixels to memory-mapped disk with resource limits.
ImageMagick for such a large image will use heavily the disk, so be prepared for
a slow conversion.

The basic command will be:

```
convert file.pbm file.png
```

However, the `jpg` format might be better for the final result, and the above link
has some advice about useful parameters that can help.